# Using SMTP Function instead of Plugin (functions.php)

Tags: wp-mail, smtp

While this works just fine, I am concerned that it poses a security threat. Does it?

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_email_using_smtp' );
function bsend_email_using_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->Host = 'mail.example.com';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->Username = 'name@example.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'your-email-account-password';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->From = 'name@example.com';
$phpmailer->FromName = 'Your company name';
}
```

Comment: What security threat are you concerned about? This action is used to setup a smtp, nothing else.

Comment: That someone, somehow, can get a hold of the SMTP credentials and use them. Or am I just "afraid" for nothing?

Comment: Unless they have administrator access this info would not be visible, direct access to the file is not allowed because of `defined('ABSPATH') || exit;`, if you have it, even if you don't this would not be visible. You could use something like bedrock which allows you to create environments and credentials before the root folder (as it changes it), that way nobody could every target those folders directly.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)